# Convert object to string Spring Boot rest API

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm receiving an `id` (integer) and a `executor` (String) in my controller (Rest API). However, when looking at my database, I see that the string is being inserted into the database as an object. Example of database entry:

```
{
    "executor": "Pietje"
}
```

*Controller:*

```
@PostMapping(path = "/accept/{id}")
public String acceptAssignment(@Valid @PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody String executor) {
    return assignmentService.acceptAssignment(id, executor);
}
```

*Service implementation:*

```
@Override
public String acceptAssignment(Integer id, String executor) {
    Assignment assignment = assignmentRespository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    
    assignment.setExecutor(String.valueOf(executor));
    
    AssignmentDTO assignmentDTO = assignmentConverter.convertEntityToDto(assignment);
    
    assignmentRespository.save(assignment);
    
    return assignmentDTO.getExecutor();
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

I could pass along the entire DTO instead of just the 'executor' value, but that doesn't seem efficient. As far as I know, the problem is not with the frontend but I could add the React code if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - you're using a `String` containing a JSON-object as if it was an attribute of this JSON-object. The solution it to treat this JSON properly.

**Note** that you **don't** need to mess with desirialization manually, let the JSON-converter of the framework do its job.

All that you need is a simple POJO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AssignmentExecutor {
    private String executor;
}
```

The above POJO can be automatically translated *in & to* the following of JSON without any effort from your side (owing to the magic of Spring):

```
{
    "executor": "Pietje"
}
```

It would be automatically parsed to the proper type by a Spring's message-converter, you only need to specify that you need an `AssignmentExecutor` instead of a plain `String`.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/accept/{id}")
public String acceptAssignment(@Valid @PathVariable Integer id,
                               @RequestBody AssignmentExecutor executor) {
    
    return assignmentService.acceptAssignment(id, executor);
}
```

**Note**

- Introducing this new type would not require any changes in the `Assignment`, executor can still be represented as a `String` field.
- By invoking `orElse(null)` on the optional result, you're creating a potential problem by depriving the possibility to get a meaningful exception if the data that corresponds to the given `id` was not found. In such a case, your current code would trigger a `NullPointerException` right on the next line. Instead, I would advise providing a suitable exception via [`Optional.orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)).

A now again all that you need is to return an instance of `AssignmentExecutor` and it would be automatically converted into JSON:

```
@Override
public String acceptAssignment(Integer id, AssignmentExecutor executor) {
    Assignment assignment = assignmentRespository.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new MyException("Assignment with id " + id + " was not found"));
    
    assignment.setExecutor(executor.getExecutor());
    assignmentRespository.save(assignment);
    
    return executor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ObjectMapper` to fetch the desired key-value from the `@RequestBody String executor` as:

**Approach Here:**

The `@RequestBody`that you are getting from the API is in the object form and using `ObjectMapper` , it will be converted into a Map of attributes as in the API request and we can fetch the desired key-value pair.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(executor, new TypeReference<>() {});
String s = (String) map.get("executor");
```

**Added in acceptAssignment method as:**

```
 @Override
  public String acceptAssignment(Integer id, String executor) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String,Object> requestMap = mapper.readValue(executor, new TypeReference<>() {});
    Assignment assignment = assignmentRespository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    assignment.setExecutor((String)requestMap.get("executor"));
    AssignmentDTO assignmentDTO = assignmentConverter.convertEntityToDto(assignment);
    assignmentRespository.save(assignment);

    return assignmentDTO.getExecutor();
  }
```